# Where we should use had had

Tags: past-perfect

Why we use single had in this sentence "Those who died yesterday had a plan for today? We use had had when something happened in the past before a past event.
Then why we don't use had had as a person had made a plan before he died in the past

Comment: _Had had_ would put the happening one stage further back in the past. "Those who _had died_ the day before had had a plan..."

Comment: But they had a plan first in the past and then they died some time later in the past

Comment: I know that! We only use the past perfect when the more recent event is referred to in the perfect tense. "Before I set out on my journey I had a good meal."  "Before I _had set out_ on my journey I _had had_ a good meal.

Comment: Not clear, a past perfect action happened before a past action. The sentence you use mean - I set out but before that I had had a good meal.

Comment: I would use my second sentence when telling of something that happened some time ago. "Before I set out (today) I had a meal" "Before I had set out (on that day I am telling you about) I had had a meal."

Answer (score 1):

Your example uses two simple past verbs, "died" and "had", because there is no time linkage, no contingency expressed between the two clauses.
You can surely infer that the plan was made before the death, but the meaning of the sentence doesn't depend on that. Yes, they had plans. Yes, they died. Those are independent events in the past.

Here are some examples that correctly use the past perfect:

"If they had had a plan, they might have avoided the attack."

"I had had a meal already, so I refused the offer for dinner."

In both of those examples, the meaning of one of the clauses in past tense depends on the other event having happened even further in the past.